# Historgrams for lists inside a list

Tags: python, list, histogram

I have a list containing 8 lists. Each sub list has length of 100 and I want to plot histograms, 4 rows 2 columns.

I want to set the title, and x and y labels. In addition to a big title to all histograms.

I tired this:

```
mytitles = ['Label 30 sub 0', 'Label 30 sub 1',
        'label 50 sub 0', 'label 50 sub 3',
        'label 50 sub 5', 'label 50 sub 6',
             'label 555', 'label 666']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=2)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
fig.suptitle('Confidence Intervals lengths')

for i in sub_list:
    plt.hist(i, bins = 20)
    for j in mytitles:
        plt.title(j)
        plt.show()
```

This however created some empty histograms.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the axes. Otherwise it will just use the last subplot.

```
for i, ax, title in zip(sub_list, axes.flat, mytitles):
    ax.hist(i, bins = 20)
    ax.set_title(title)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you please also add how should I add labels to the x and y axis? For x I want to label `CI differences` and for y just label `count`.

Comment: You can do the with `ax.set_xlabel` and `ax.set_ylabel`